# Python / xldr : How do I pull data from an excel file using a raw_input variable?

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

So I am trying to make a simple ballistics calculator for the game Arma 3 with python 2.7 and an excel file. The intent is to make a simple program that runs in the terminal that asks for the data involved in the shot you are trying to calculate, and output a value that is equal to the mil-dot hold over (the dots in a sniper scope) you need for a successful shot on target. The link with the example table will explain in detail what this involves. It is pretty simple.

It involves doing a trigonometric calculation to find the true, horizontal distance to the target. Then using that range in combination with a value (parsed? using xlrd) from an excel file that contains a variable used in the hold over calculation.

i.e. horizontal distance = range * cos(angle)

horizontal distance - zeroing = hold_over_variable_x ;

then use [a table from this steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=416223117) to get another variable used in hold over calculation. In this example the M320 LRR rifle's table, which will be saved in an excel file. (I would like to add more rifles in the future, and use a raw_input variable to pick the corresponding excel sheet)

The zeroing will be a variable that is assigned through raw_input, and is needed to pull the correct value from said table.

e.g. zeroing = 1000

range = 1125

angle = 15.5

horizontal distance = 1125 cos(15.5) = 1100

horizontal distance - zeroing = 100 = hold_over_variable_x

hold_over_variable_y = -1.5 (parsed from excel file using zeroing variable)

hold_over = 100 * -1.5 = -150

hold_over would ideally print as -1.5.

## Here is my code currently, sorry for the poor formatting *edit; proper formatting for initial code:

```
zeroing = int(raw_input("Zeroing?"))

designator_range = int(raw_input("Range?"))

angle = float(raw_input("Angle?"))

from math import cos, radians

horizontal_distance = designator_range * cos (radians(angle))

import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('mildot_arma.xls')

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('M320')

hold_over_variable_x = horizontal_distance - zeroing

if zeroing == 300:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(1,1).value

elif zeroing == 400:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(2,1).value

elif zeroing == 500:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(3,1).value

elif zeroing == 600:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(4,1).value

elif zeroing == 700:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(5,1).value

elif zeroing == 800:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(6,1).value

elif zeroing == 900:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(7,1).value

elif zeroing == 1000:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(8,1).value

elif zeroing == 1100:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(9,1).value

elif zeroing == 1200:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(10,1).value

elif zeroing == 1300:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(11,1).value

elif zeroing == 1400:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(12,1).value

elif zeroing == 1500:

    hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(13,1).value

else:
    hold_over_variable_y = sheet.cell(14,1).value

hold_over = hold_over_variable_x * hold_over_variable_y

print hold_over
```

I am getting the errors:

```
Using variable 'hold_over_variable_y' before assignment 
Undefined variable 'sheet'
```

Starting when I hit the if functions.

I am super noob at this. Sorry for the giant post. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

## *Edit #2:

Lars knew exactly what I needed to fix. Was using == in places I should have been using =, and I needed to change sheet.cell to worksheet.cell. This is my first actual project that could be useful for me and I am kinda proud of it. Thanks for all the help.

Here is the code as it is now. Going to try and put it all under while True: hoping it will let me input new data and calculate the next shot without closing the terminal.

```
#Horizontal distance and Mil-dot Hold Calculator for M320 in Arma 3

#Asks for ballistic data to assign values to variables that will be used in range and mil-dot calculations
zeroing = int(raw_input("Zeroing?"))
designator_range = int(raw_input("Range?"))
angle = float(raw_input("Angle?"))

#Imports cos and radians from math module
from math import cos, radians

#Trigonometric, horizontal distance calculation. Converts angle to radian and multiplies its cosine with the designator range.
horizontal_distance = designator_range * cos (radians(angle))

#Imports excel workbook, 'mildot_arma.xls", worksheet 'M320'. A mil-dot balistics table for the M320 to be used in hold over calculation
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('mildot_arma.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('M320')

#Beginning of Mil-dot calculation process

#Creates hold over variable_x from distance minus zeroing to be calculated with sheet
hold_over_variable_x = horizontal_distance - zeroing

#Parses hold over variable_y from sheet to be calculated with previous variable, (the most complicated part)
if zeroing == 300:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(1,1).value
elif zeroing == 400:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(2,1).value
elif zeroing == 500:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(3,1).value
elif zeroing == 600:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(4,1).value
elif zeroing == 700:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(5,1).value
elif zeroing == 800:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(6,1).value
elif zeroing == 900:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(7,1).value
elif zeroing == 1000:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(8,1).value
elif zeroing == 1100:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(9,1).value
elif zeroing == 1200:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(10,1).value
elif zeroing == 1300:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(11,1).value
elif zeroing == 1400:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(12,1).value
elif zeroing == 1500:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(13,1).value
else:
    hold_over_variable_y = worksheet.cell(14,1).value

#Calculates mil-dot hold over from variables, and assigns mil-dot hold over value
hold_over = hold_over_variable_x * hold_over_variable_y

#Prints final hold over calculation
print hold_over
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. There is a special button for that in the [edit]ing interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error tells you there is no variable named sheet defined in your code but you are calling a function on sheet. *You might need to rename sheet to worksheet.*

The variable hold_over_variable_y is also not defined before you use it. Give it a value before you compare it to something. 
e.g. here:
`hold_over_variable_y == sheet.cell(1,1).value` 
How would you know if this is true or false if hold_over_variable_y doesn't have a value?

Comment: You rock! That is exactly what I needed to change. I edited my question with the fixed code. This is my first project I have ever done in coding, so I really appreciate the help.